# Angular library ng-packagr doesn't replace tsconfig paths with relative paths

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-packagr

I have an Angular workspace (v10.0.2) containing a library and an app (for testing the library).

Inside my `projects/libname/src/lib/tsconfig.lib.json` I have some paths:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
  "@lib/*": ["lib/*"]
}
```

And I use it like this:

```js
import { DateUtils } from '@lib/utils/date.utils';
```

I get this warning:

> WARNING: No name was provided for external module '@lib/utils/date.utils' in output.globals – guessing 'date_utils'

AFAIK, this means the tsconfig paths aren't replaced so `ng-packagr` is considering it as an external module. When I looked into the `dist` folder I saw `'@lib/utils/date.utils'` still presents and is not replaced with the relative path. If I ignore the warning, when I serve the test app, it gives this error:

> Cannot find module '@lib/utils/date' or its corresponding type declarations.

I've searched a lot and read lots of issues snd SO questions, found no solutions.

Comment: Sadly it looks like this is not supported by ng-packagr. Pretty tragic because this is such a big feature to not include. Here's a link to a thread where one of the devs doesn't support it. https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/519#issuecomment-461487097

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found is to choose a prefix so that your paths will be exactly the same when the package is installed in `node_modules`

For example, if your package name is `xyz`, you tsconfig will be:

```
"paths": {
  "xyz/*": ["lib/*"]
}
```

I highly recommend using sub-entries as it not only solved this issue, but also it'll support tree shaking. [This article](https://tomastrajan.medium.com/the-best-way-to-architect-your-angular-libraries-87959301d3d3) will help